# Is there a standard cryptographic library in python for generating the AES key schedule?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, aes

I have been working on AES algorithm and have implemented the AES program for basic encryption and decryption.

As the AES uses a key schedule for generating the keys (or subkeys) of each round, the standard `pycrypto` library in python doesn't focus particularly on the internal details of AES algorithm.

I want to generate and test the time it takes for AES to generate its key schedule for some research purpose and hence, I want to implement only the Key Generation/Key Schedule part of the AES algorithm. Is there any library/method (in python) through which I can do the same?

Also, I would like to generate the key schedule from predefined string, i.e. a random string/password can be used as the first subkey for the key schedule.

Comment: This is all open source, right? There is no particular reason why, as a user, you'd just want the AES key schedule. If you're going to test the *speed of the implementation* then it also doesn't make sense to switch implementation anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There's some research work that I am currently working on that needs this switch in the implementation, and hence, I just need the key schedule.

Comment: Well, did you try and extract it from the source as I've indicated? As said, the chance that you'll find an API for just the key schedule is not high.